# Sum total duration of exams

Tags: mysql

I have table exams with fields:

```
id - int(10) UNSIGNED,
name - varchar(255)
duration - int(10) UNSIGNED
```

with records:

```
Exam A 3600 
Exam B 3600
```

and need to sum their total duration but result is not correct when try convert them to UNIXTIME with this code:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(SUM(duration), '%H:%i') AS totalDuration
FROM
    exams
```

So total result is: 04 hrs : 00 mins

Guess the problem is in conversion?

Comment: is the duration in seconds and why do you need to convert into UNIXTIME?.It seems you need to convert seconds to hours,right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(duration)),'%Hh %im')
FROM
    exams
```

Because it's not a UNIX time, it's a lapse of time in seconds

Comment: Thank you, logic is simple and you're right it's not UNIX time :)

Comment: So problem appear when work with big numbers. E.g when have 2216 hrs 66 mins, MySQL show only 839h 59m because SEC_TO_TIME have limitation: -839:59:59 to 839:59:59